# Create a page that can be used for different URLs

Tags: url-rewriting

How can I create a page that can be served for different URLs?

I'd like to write one page with HTML and JavaScript content, and have the JavaScript decide what content to have on the page.

```
example.com/states/Hawaii   
example.com/states/Ohio
example.com/states/Washington
example.com/states/California
```

How can I write one page that will be served on each of these URLs?

Answer (score 2):

First, create a single `states` page.

Add a query var to hold the state value, `wpd_state`:

```
function wpd_query_vars( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'wpd_state';
    return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpd_query_vars' , 10, 1 );
```

Add a rewrite rule to capture the state from the URL, set the `wpd_state` query var, and load the page `states`:

```
function wpd_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'states/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=states&wpd_state=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_filter( 'init', 'wpd_rewrite_rule' );
```

You can then use `get_query_var( 'wpd_state' )` to fetch the requested state, which you can use to pass to your [enqueued javascript](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) via [`wp_localize_script`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).